# Calling a C++ dll from reporting services report

Tags: c#, c++, reporting-services, pinvoke

My company currently has a product that uses crystal reports.  These reports make a call out to a custom C++ dll (CRUFL) with a lot of business logic for populating certain fields on the crystal reports.  My company wishes to have the product switched to use Reporting Services instead of crystal reports and I have been tasked with investigating how to re-use the CRUFL dll with reporting services.

My following question deals specifically with the investigation path I've taken so far, but I would be more than open to any and all suggestions on how else to solve this issue.

On another product we already use reporting services and make custom code calls from the rdl files to a C# dll.  Armed with this knowledge, I thought I should be able to write a C# wrapper dll that makes P\Invoke calls to the C++ dll.

I started by writing my own C++ code (to keep it simple) and added a very basic method to return some text (it may be clear that I know only the most basic of C++).  In my CPPFile.cpp I have:

```
extern "C"
{   
    __declspec(dllexport) void ReturnTextFromDLL(char* & rtnStr)
    {
        rtnStr = "Some return string from inside the cpp dll! \n";
    }
}
```

I then wrote a C# wrapper both containing the call to the c++ method above as well as a testing method that doesn't make a call to c++:

```
public static class WrapperClass
{
    [DllImport("TestCPP.dll")]
    public static extern void ReturnTextFromDLL(out string output);

    public static string DisplayHardcodedText()
    {
        return "Some hardcoded text in WrapperClass";
    }
}
```

Now, I created a simple RDL with two textboxes.  Under Report Properties, I added a reference to my C# dll (CSharpWrapper) and added the following under code:

```
Shared Function GetTextFromCPP() As String
Dim rtnStr As String = ""
CSharpWrapper.WrapperClass.ReturnTextFromDLL(rtnStr)
Return rtnStr
End Function 

Shared Function GetHardCodedTextFromWrapper() As String
Return CSharpWrapper.WrapperClass.DisplayHardcodedText()
End Function
```

For the textboxes' Expression, I have:

`=Code.GetTextFromCPP()`

and

`=Code.GetHardCodedTextFromWrapper()`

I also copied both the C++ and C# dll into my \Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.

When I preview the report, the textbox that calls GetHardCodedTextFromWrapper() displays 'Some hardcoded text in WrapperClass'.

However, the textbox that should be displaying the text from the C++ method only shows "#Error".  In the output window I get:

> "The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission"

I did take this one step back and tested outside of reporting services by writing a quick C# console application and it worked without issues.

I also tried fully deploying the report with the report manager & deploying my dlls to the \ReportServer\bin but it gave the exact same result.

So I guess what I'm asking is if it is even possible in reporting services to do this?  If so, what do I need to do to get passed the SecurityPermission?

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Comment: You might want to put a c# wrapper on the p/invoke and put some try catch around it to see if any exceptions were thrown. You may also be able to use Debugger.Launch() or Debugger.Break() to attach your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception you are probably not running in "full trust" which is required to call unmanaged code. If you are hosting this in IIS you will need to change the application pool configuration, if you are running from a standalone executable you will need to change the trust level in the project settings.

Comment: Hi Yaur, thanks for your suggestions, but I have two questions:

1. re - app pool configuration - in SQL 2008 there is no entry in IIS for reporting services.  Is there another way to make changes to the app pool config that you are refering to?

2.  re. Changing the trust level in the project settings - I have two projects, the C# wrapper project and the C++ project, should I  do both?  Is it possible to change the trust level of a C++ project?

Thanks again!

Comment: A quick update, I created a very quick ASP.net project, added a button and a textbox, and on button click, make a call out to the WrapperClass.ReturnTextFromDLL method.  I also added a reference to the C# dll, and then manually dropped the C++ dll in the bin folder.  This worked without issue.

I noticed the Web.Config defaulted to full trust, so I changed it to 'High', and I got the SecurityPermission error.

So, I then checked every Web.config I could find for reporting services, but both already had Full trust set.  I'm not sure if the configs are different reporting services. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with reporting services specifically but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866.aspx may be of some help in finding the web.config for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the new DLL assembly in the RDL file. Example:

```
<CodeModules>
<CodeModule>DLL INFO</CodeModule>
</CodeModules>
```

For more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx

If you're using VS, you can just go to the design view > Report Properties > References > Add Assemblies